# What do you call a tree that grows in both directions?

Tags: computer-science, trees

[image: tree representation]What would be the technical term for a tree that grows in both the directions, starting from the root in the middle?

The central idea being that new elements can be added to the tree (Now, I am not sure if it is even okay to call it one) in both the directions. But, when used for traversal purposes, you need to follow the directed links.

Comment: It seems to me that a tree doesn't grow in any direction; this is merely convention. You could choose to draw a binary tree with the "lesser" elements growing downwards and the "greater" elements growing upwards, instead of left and right. Additionally, I'm almost sure "name that thing"-type questions aren't allowed here.

Comment: I think the fact that you made some of the children above and some below is conceptually irrelevant. Can you provide more information about this data structure?

Comment: Assuming directed edges, then this could make sense, though it would seem the direction of the edge is being use to represent a separate tree.

Comment: In addition, this particular question lacks any context.  For my part, I've never actually seen a binary tree that grows in the manner you describe, unless you're talking about left and right subtrees, in which case, you're describing a Binary Tree.

Comment: It's still a tree. How is the "down" portion and the "up" portion different from a left subtree and a right subtree? I mean, yeah, you drew a subtree coming *up* from the root instead of *down*, but can you prove there's a significant difference, other than visual representation?

Comment: The precise technical term for this is "tree".

Comment: I have added a better image representation for the tree. I am more interested in knowing about any technical terms we use to refer such trees by so I don't agree with this question being like a guessing game.

Comment: Adding "** EDIT **" and other similar monikers to your questions is not necessary. Every question on the Stack Exchange network comes with a detailed revision history that anyone can review.  The revision history for this question can be found here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/231641/revisions

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Sure. Thanks for letting me know about it.

Comment: I call it a graph.

Comment: -1. After the edit, it's unclear what you're asking.  Labelling things 'prefix', 'suffix', and 'root' makes it look like you're asking a question about a specific representation of words with prefixes and suffixes on them.  Are the 'prefixes' and 'suffixes' different?  If I had one of these data structures, I have no idea what I can do with it.  Can I follow the directed links backwards to add another prefix?  If so, are they really directed links?  What have you tried?  Have you tried reading the 'tree' page on wikipedia?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a couple simple categories you can fit graphs into that makes it easier to classify them.

- Directed: This is a graph wherein you have parent-child relations that are one way, that is the child may not directly reference the parent
- Undirected: This is a graph wherein you have node-node relations, they are not parent-child and may go either way
- Acyclic: This is a graph that does not have any cycles in it, this means none of the nodes may reference a node which directly or indirectly references it, that is to say it may not reference one of it's ancestors
- Cyclic: This is a graph that may have cycles in it, this means any node may reference any node
- Balanced: This is a directed graph with any path being up to the length of N+-1, when drawn it's recognizable because it looks symmetric and the childless nodes all live within 1 height level of eachother.
- Binary: This is a directed graph where every node has no more than 2 children.

The graph you have drawn, is a **Directed Acyclic Graph**, often called a DAG for short. Most things we refer to as "trees" fall into this category, people don't usually call graphs that are either undirected or cyclic "trees" because when you draw one, it doesn't give off the appearance of having a root which is grown from as trees do. People usually resort to the term "graph" in the case of non-DAGs

---

Above are the commonly seen and well known classifiers, digging around Wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) you may find others which are less known such as:

- Rooted: This is a graph with a single root node (your specific example may be called unrooted, though very few people are likely to recognize this terminology)
- Symmetric: Genuinely; I don't know off hand.
- Complete: A complete graph is a graph where all nodes have direct references to all other nodes.

Answer (score 8):

A tree is a special kind of graph. More specifically, it's ["any connected graph without simple cycles"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29). So, your graph is a tree. It doesn't matter if it grows or not. Yours is a directed graph so it doesn't really matter anyways. It's not a binary tree, if that's what you were asking =)

Comment: Calling it just a tree would be something that I may now go with. I was hoping it'd be called something like a "bidirectional tree" (from bi-directional search) but that does seem to represent other things.

Comment: It doesn't have any special name AFAIK, but I'm hardly a math expert. Even as I read the Wikipedia article, there seems to be a distinction between directed and undirected trees, so this may not even be considered a tree in some scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there is a special name for this, it's simply a tree. "Growing in both directions" is purely an artifact of how you drew the tree.

Also, it's a little hard to tell from your ASCII art, but if the top and bottom are connected and you have cycles, then this is technically not a tree at all, but a graph (of which trees are a more specific case).

Based on the updated picture, this is not a tree at all but a directed graph. What is labeled as "root" cannot be a root because it has multiple edges leading into it. A tree is a very specific sort of Directed Acyclic Graph, which this is, but has the additional constraint that it must have only a single node without any edges leading into it. That node is the root. As you can see, none of the nodes in your graph can satisfy this definition.

Comment: I have added a better representation of the tree.

Comment: Did you draw that representation yourself, or did you get it from somewhere?  If you got it from somewhere on the Internet, tell us where you got it from so that we can go there and draw on some context.  If you're reading this description from a book, tell us what book it is and share some of the author's relevant prose.

Comment: No, this is my own representation. The central idea being that new elements can be added to the tree (Now, I am not sure if it is even okay to call it one) in both the directions. But, when used for traversal purposes, you need to follow the directed links.

Comment: I updated my answer given the new representation. What you are talking about is not a tree at all.

Comment: Traversal is independent of adding new elements to the tree.  I think you're just looking at an ordinary Binary Tree.  Look up Tree Traversal on Wikipedia.

Comment: @Evicatos: The arrows represent traversal, not the tree's shape.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ok, I'm a little unsure of my answer now, but I'm still fairly sure that it doesn't qualify as a tree at this point. In order to traverse it you'd have to store the leaf nodes with outgoing edges so you're still talking about a graph. I believe that a tree, by definition, needs to be single-rooted and there's no way to traverse this structure to get to the leaves unless you are already storing references to those leaves. It definitely isn't a binary tree because the node labeled root has more than 2 edges.

Comment: @Robert: Oh I am sorry, it think it's my bad that I have been confusing the terminology but the nodes labelled "pre" and "post" simply signify that they appear before or after the "root" during traversal. They are not related to the pre and post traversals in the traditional sense. I am changing them to "prefix" and "suffix". I hope that this one doesn't lead to more confusion.

Comment: @gat: All this trouble, and you're merely looking for a name?  We're not a lookup service; we're here to help you with whatever the thing is, not give it a name.  Moving the goalposts doesn't help.  How can you expect us to know what the name is if you're not even clear on the terminology for describing it?

Comment: I am just concerned if we already have a name for it. For example, it would be wrong to name a "graph" as "linked-nodes" if I didn't know the proper name for it. Hence my question.

Comment: Every tree is also a graph.  Just call it a graph, if you're merely trying to have a conversation with your coworkers without looking stupid.

Comment: That probably sounds like the best suggestion till now. Except the fact that I am looking for something to put in written literature.

Comment: @Evicatos It's a tree, any way you look at it. Only, the root it specifies is not a root at all.

Comment: @ArthurChamz reading your wikipedia link, yes you are correct. I have to admit my Math is rusty as hell so I didn't realize that mathematically this is still a tree. When was the last time you worked with a tree that wasn't singly-rooted though? I still stand behind my answer of "this is a graph" if you're trying to convey what it is to your average developer.

Comment: @Evicatos Math, I hate it that a love it =( I was actually trying to figure out if there was a special kind of tree that had this characteristics in Wikipedia, but I couldn't find anything. Not yet, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

A tree is any acyclic graph.

In an undirected tree, any node can be the root, since all edges are undirected and therefore there's no 'parent / child' relationship.  Most of these aren't typically thought as trees and aren't drawn as such, but all the mathematical definitions apply.

In a directed tree, usually there's a single root, if you define if the direction of edges are 'child->parent' or 'parent->child'.  Which one is usually an implementation detail: in-memory structures typically have pointers from parent to children, relational databases use foreign keys from children to parent.

Note that a directed tree can have no root if the direction of the arcs don't represent a parent/child relationship.  This is still a three, but most of the implementation simplifications typical of a directed three are less obvious.  In that case, an implementation could either treat the three as undirected, or add an underlying rooted tree by labeling the parent/child relationships separately.

In this case the edge direction is drawn inconsistently, but I guess any implementation would pick one and flip the arrows of one half, so you end with a pretty standard rooted tree.  Of course, to keep the 'prefix' subtree separate from the 'suffix' one, i would either use two independent trees, or initialize the root with two fixed nodes ('prefix' and 'suffix') and grow each one independently.